# PowerShell : Rename files names with math operation, arithmetics (+, -, *, /, %, [math]::floor etc.)

Tags: powershell, math, file-rename, integer-arithmetic

I would like to **rename files names in folder using math operation**.

The simplest **example** for multiply *2 of n-th element doesn't work:

```
cd c:\my_folder\
$n = 38
ls | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | %{Rename-Item $_ $n*2"$($_.Extension)";  $n--}
```

I tried many way (int), [math], position change and many others. I read exemples on many websides and nothing works.

Below is expected file name **pattern** depending on `$n` - number of file sorted by the oldest file (first).

```
$n/2 + 4*(1+[math]::floor($n/9).ToString())) - 3.5*(($n+2)%2
```

Only pattern *not renaming* *code* works in this code:

```
for ($n = 1; $n -lt 16; $n++) { ($n/2 + 4*(1+[math]::floor($n/9).ToString())) - 3.5*(($n+2)%2)}
```

Can someone help me? I will be grateful.

Thank you in advance

**BTW:  In the code below file renaming works from newest to oldest, but will be better in other way.*

```
ls | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | %{Rename-Item $_ $n"$($_.Extension)";  $n--}
```

(✔️) *Second Question SOLVED - anwser in first comment*

Comment: As for the order; `ls | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending`.

Comment: @notjustme thank you very much . Hmm... it was quite simple, I didn't focus on this. My fault, it worked somehow thx. **But** **main** **problem** **is** **still** **unsolved** 

Comment: The formula you've given has collisions - `$n=10` and `$n=17` both evaluate to `13` for example. How do you want to handle those?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, you are correct. Good point. In the future it will be changed to "13(1).png" or formula will be reorganized, now I change for limit to 16.

Comment: @phuclv Done. I hope it's ok now.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It is possibile, this cannot be done (solution of main problem)?